# Parsing JSON with Glom

Tags: python, json, glom

I am trying to parse a JSON object and am having a difficult time accessing a value in a way that I can then merge with another df. The path for the value is: `QueryResponse.Purchase[0].Line[0].Amount`

This spec will give me the first value:

```
glom(data, ('QueryResponse.Purchase', ['Line'], (['0'], ['Amount'])))
```

but not the `Amounts` contained in the other `Lines`. I can access the other `Amount` values, but then have not been able to figure out how to merge that with my df containing values from the `Purchase` level

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Glom Tutorial](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), you need to specify the "data" before using it in a glom methode.

Example (from there site):

```
from glom import glom

# Basic deep get

data = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}

print(glom(data, 'a.b.c'))
```

In your case, you'll also need to import Json at the top (but you probably already did that).

Answer (score 1):

Without a data example, it's a little hard to assist with the issue.

However, assuming your data looks something like this:

```
data = {"QueryResponse": 
          {"Purchase": [
             {"Line": {"Amount": 10}}, 
             {"Line": {"Amount": 20}}
            ]
          }
        }
```

Then the query to get all of the `Amount` values from each `Line` entry puts the full path to the desired value in the list.

```
>>> glom(data, ('QueryResponse.Purchase', ['Line.Amount']))
[10, 20]
```